# Exterior square of multiset in representation theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, multisets

```
General Setting:
```

In a paper I'm working on, the author uses multisets to describe the representation theory of the cyclic group $G = C_n = <\sigma>$ of order $n$. Let $\varphi_i$ denote the absolutely irreducible characters of $G$, defined by the action of $\sigma$ on the $n$-th primitive root of unity $\zeta_n$ by $\sigma \cdot \zeta_n = \zeta_n ^{\varphi_i(\sigma)}$. So $\varphi_i(\sigma)$ are just elements of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

For a representation $V$ of a group $G$ he denotes by 
$$A(V) = \{<\varphi_i, \chi(V)> \varphi_i(\sigma), i = 0, \dots, n-1\}$$
the *multiset corresponding to the decomposition of the $G$-module $V$*. Here, $\chi(V)$ denotes the character of $V$ and the scalar product is just the usual inner product.

For an arbitrary multiset $A = \{a_0,\dots,a_n\}$ he then defines the *exterior square* as 
$$\bigwedge\nolimits^2(A) = \{a_i + a_j, i<j\}$$ which corresponds to the definition found for example in [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=FE36E1F5CF136F0C081A406C8D29F964?doi=10.1.1.37.2934&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper - though I haven't really found a reference for this notation.

```
Claim:
```

The main point now is the following: He claims that the multiset associated to the exterior square representation of $V$ is equal to the exterior square of the multiset associated to $V$.

```
Problem:
```

The problem I'm having with this is now, that the multiset associated to $V$ has at most $n$ elements, corresponding to the $n$ absolutely irreducible characters of $C_n$ over a suitable field extension whereas the exterior square of this multiset does have exactly $\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)$ elements. So why should this be a multiset associated to the exterior square of a representation? I think the exterior square of any representation (character) just has at most $n$ irreducible characters as constituents with maybe different multiplicities. Where am I wrong with this?

```
Example (Character of a cyclic group of order 3):
```

To make my question clear, let's work out an example:
Let $n=3$ and $\chi(V) = 3 \varphi_0 + 2 \varphi_2$ be a the character decomposition of $V$ in  the absolutely irreducible characters $\varphi_0$ (trivial) and $\varphi_2$ (the character sending $\sigma \mapsto \zeta_3^2$.) 
The multiset associated to $V$ is then
$$A(V) = \{0,0,1\}$$
because 
$$<\varphi_0, \chi(V)> \varphi_0(\sigma) = 2 * 0 = 0$$ 
$$<\varphi_1, \chi(V)> \varphi_1(\sigma) = 0 * 1 = 0$$
$$<\varphi_2, \chi(V)> \varphi_2(\sigma) = 2 * 2 = 4 \equiv 1 \mod 3$$

The exterior square associated to this multiset is then
$$\bigwedge\nolimits^2 A(V) = \{0,1,1\}$$
for obvious reasons.
If we calculate the exterior square of our representation $V$, we get the following character decomposition:
$$\chi(\bigwedge\nolimits^2 V) = 3\varphi_0 + \varphi_1 + 6\varphi_2$$
so the associated multiset is 
$$A(\bigwedge\nolimits^2 V) = \{0,0,1\}$$
because
$$<\varphi_0, \chi(V)> \varphi_0(\sigma) = 3 * 0 = 0$$ 
$$<\varphi_1, \chi(V)> \varphi_1(\sigma) = 1 * 1 = 1$$ 
$$<\varphi_2, \chi(V)> \varphi_2(\sigma) = 6 * 2 = 12 \equiv 0 \mod 3$$
So there obviously the multiset which are supposed to be the same, do not agree, since

$$A(\bigwedge\nolimits^2 V) = \{0,0,1\} \neq \{0,1,1\} = \bigwedge\nolimits^2 A(V)$$

Is my example alright? Do you see the problem or am I misscalculating or -understanding something?

Thank you very much! :-)

Tom

Comment: I'd guess that the definitions are meant such that in your example, $A(V)=\{0,0,0,2,2\}$ and the multiset corresponding to the exterior square is $\{0,0,0,1,2,2,2,2,2,2\}$. In other words, $\phi_i(\sigma)$ occurs $\langle \phi_i, \chi(V) \rangle$-times in $A(V)$.

Comment: @ladisch Thank you very much for that hint! That was exactly what I needed though I really don't think that this definition is a good one. Maybe it is just that I'm not familiar with multisets, but I would definitely say that this definition is not clear. What do you think?

Comment: Well, the definition of $A(V)$ you cite is, I think, very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the definition of the multiset $A(V)$ associated to the representation $V$ was formally incorrect. Let me give a formal correct definition:

> $A(V) = (S, \pi)$ with
>
> $S = \{\phi_i(\sigma) | i = 0, \dots, n-1\} \subset \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and
> $\pi: S \to \mathbb{N}_0, \phi_i(\sigma) \mapsto <\phi_i,\chi(V)>$

I will compute the example I've given above with this right definition later.